# Need help...selecting HTML tags from within conditional comments using XPath

Tags: c#, xpath

I'm somewhat new to `XPath` so forgive me in advance.  I'd like to be able to search HTML comments, conditional comments in particular and return only certain tags such as `<link>` and `<script>`.

So far I've been able to return a collection of the comments that contain those tags with: `//comment()[contains(.,'link') or contains(.,'script')]`, but at this point, I'm not sure how to extract the actual tags themselves as nodes with attributes.

Can anyone help me please?

Here's an example from what I'm trying to retrieve various elements from:
I need to able to grab the link and script elements.  Probably should have also mentioned I'm using C# and the HTML Agility Pack.

```
<head>
    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/layout/css/IE7.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/layout/css/IE9.css" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

> So far I've been able to return a collection of the comments that
>   contain those tags with: `//comment()[contains(.,'link') or
>   contains(.,'script')]`, but at this point, I'm not sure how to extract
>   the actual tags themselves as nodes with attributes.

This cannot be done, because at the time of XPath expression evaluation there are no nodes inside the comment -- just string.

What can be done is to get the wanted *strings*.

**For example, the result of evaluating this XPath expression when the context node is one of the two comments**:

```
   "substring-before(substring-after(., '>'),
                     '&lt;![endif]'
                     )
```

**is, respectively:**:

```
  &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="/layout/css/IE7.css" /&gt;

  &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="/layout/css/IE9.css" /&gt;
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="comment()">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "substring-before(substring-after(., '>'),
                     '&lt;![endif]'
                     )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<head>
    <!--[if IE 7]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/layout/css/IE7.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/layout/css/IE9.css" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated on each comment node and the result of this evaluation is output:**

```
  &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="/layout/css/IE7.css" /&gt;

  &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="/layout/css/IE9.css" /&gt;
```

Comment: Is there any way to incorporate the substring portion into the following xpath "SelectNodes" statment?: //comment()[contains(.,'link') or contains(.,'script')]

Comment: @MarcS.: No, this is a string -- XPath works on a set of *nodes* -- the XML Infoset. In order for this to become possible, the string must first be successfully parsed to an XML document -- this cannot be accomplished within XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0 -- the host programming language must do the parsing and then evaluate another XPath expression against the result of this parsing operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the element name (what you call "tag" is called an element in XML/XPath parlance) this will select it and all attached nodes - which includes all the attributes of the element.

So, if you document looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" />
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

You could use the following XPath:

```
/html/head/link
```

The returned node set will contain all `link` element and you can then query them for the attribute values.

---

Update:

Seeing the sample markup, things are bit more complicated... You are using IE conditional comments.

This makes the items *within* them appear as *comments* to all browsers/parsers *except* for IE. This is a problem as you want to retrieve the `<link>` "elements" embedded in the comments.

You would need to strip out the conditional comments yourself - a specialized hand written parser might be the best option, as the HAP will only see comments here.

Comment: Thanks for the nomenclature definition.

Comment: Thanks.  I sort of figured I might have to do that.  Which isn't the end of the world.

Comment: I really don't need the HAP to see them as "real" elements.  I'd be happy, for what I need to do, to get them back as text strings.

Comment: @MarcS. - The HAP can get the comments no problem, but these will need to be parsed again differently.